# How to add a different file than index.html on nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration

So I'm fairly new at this and I have a nginx server up and running to a simple web-page. The configuration that I have on `sites-available` is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/mywebsite/;
    index /html/index.html;

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

And my index.html is located at this structure:

```
+------+   +----------+    
+ html +-->+index.html|    
+------+   +----------+    
       |      
       |   +--------------+
       +-->+scnd_page.html|
           +--------------+
```

When I access `mywebsite.com`, I see `index.html`. How could I make `mywebsite.com/scnd_page/` to point to `send_page.html`?

I've tried some stuff creating

```
location /scnd_page { 
}
```

But I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Is this even to be done on this file?

Comment: try to see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037716/how-to-redirect-single-url-in-nginx

Comment: I think that's what I need. I'll try it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite) to make sure to issue external redirects, such that the `.html` would never be visible to the user, and [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/r/try_files) to serve the actual files.

```
location / {
    rewrite     ^(/.*)\.html$   $1  redirect;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html =404;
}
```

I wouldn't recommend supporting a trailing slash `/$` to imply `\.html$`, though; the logic for such support would be a bit ugly, plus it'll also cause extra issues if you try to use relative URLs within said `scnd_page.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just configure the index parameter inside the location block:

`location /html/scnd_page {
       index scnd_page.html; 
}`

Also you can just define as "secondary" index the scnd_page.html globally:

`server {`

```
listen 80 default_server;

root /var/www/mywebsite/;
# carefull setting '/html/index.html'...
index index.html scnd_page.html;

server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

}